# How to detect the OS type of a SSH client from the remote OS

Tags: bash, ssh, putty

If I am using PuTTY from Windows to SSH to a remote OS, how do I detect what OS the SSH client is running on, from within the remote OS?

I think this is probably impossible. Merely the terminal type of a SSH client is [difficult](https://serverfault.com/questions/350401/detect-terminal-type-with-tput) to detect.

Comment: You mean the SSH server? The client is PuTTY on your side.

Comment: @Matteo I mean the type of the OS PuTTY is running on.

Comment: If you're looking for a command from SSH to get remote OS, you can try [cat /etc/*-release], [uname -a], or [cat /proc/version] but those will likely work only with linux